# “System”, “software”, “application” or “tool” – which to use in my paper?

Tags: publications, computer-science, software, terminology

I am in the field of computer science, I developed some software to solve some problems and would like to write some papers about them. But I don’t know what to call the software in each of my works.

For example I developed software to extract structured data from web pages, (I called it *system*). In another project I developed software for foreign language learning (I called it *software tool,* however I may rather to call it *system* again).

In general, what is the difference between *software* and *system?* 
When I should use the terms *application* or *tool?*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about computing jargon, not academia

Comment: I think this could stay open since it asks a question I interpret to be about academic publication/presentation.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers thousands of publications include these terms, for example system, then it is not just about computing, other fields also may develop software for their works

Comment: In your first sentence, you write "I developed some software...", so I think you've answered your own question.

Comment: @JeffE thank you but any other word I had used, you would say the same

Comment: @Ahmad That's correct.  The first word that occurs to you to use is usually the right one.

Comment: System = not necessarily a "software", "application" or "tool". In its broadest sense, a systematic approach to solving a problem. Software = a configuration of hardware amenable to being programmed. Application = a system that is not solely of theoretical interest. Tool = a system that is mainly useful for creating other useful things rather than a system that achieves an appreciable goal of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In academic writing, it is good to be precise, clear, and consistent in your use of terms and their definitions.  Unfortunately, not everyone in Computer Science follows this practice when it comes to terms like "system", "application", "software", and "tool". Following the practices of other people may lead you to follow their ambiguous or loose usage.

---

One useful way of thinking about each of these terms is to **define them in terms of their opposite, or what distinctions they are drawing**.

For example, a "system" is a set of interrelated components (modules, subsystems, etc.) that work together to form some cohesive whole, especially when the performance or functions of the whole is more than the sum of the parts.  In contrast, a "non-system" is a collection of components (parts, modules, subsystems) that *do not* cohere as a whole and have no significant interrelatedness.  (Look up "General Systems Theory" for more on this distinction.)

"Software" as a term is most meaningful when you use it to distinguish from "hardware" or even non-automated information processing by humans.  However, it is also generic, like "program", and so it can refer to any code that runs on digital computer.

An "application" is software that is not part of the operating system, and not part of the utilities that go with the operation system (e.g. database, compiler, networking utilities.)  By implication, "application software" is what *end users* use to get value from computers, as opposed to "system software" which is what computer specialists use to create/support application software.  (This terminology arose in business computing in the 1960s, and continued through the early 2000s).

A "tool" is software that doesn't provide end-user value on it's own.  It generally needs a "tool user", usually a skilled human but could be another software program in special circumstances.  A "tool" performs a set of functions that are generally useful and not tied to any particular circumstance, problem, or approach.  Tools are often are designed with general use in mind (e.g. easy interchange with other programs using standard interfaces and data formats).  In contrast, software that is *not* a "tool" has features, functions, and interfaces that constrain it to a particular need, context, or purpose, and it is these specifics that make it valuable.  For example, Microsoft Excel is a "tool" for math, but a sales commission calculator within a CRM system is generally not considered a "tool" even though it may perform spreadsheet-like math, because it has many specific features and functions unique to sales commissions at a particular company.

Finally, in academic papers in Computer Science, it is often the case that what is most important is *not* the particular implementation of software, but instead it is the *algorithm* or maybe the *software architecture* that is most important.  If so, then you should use those terms rather than the more generic "software" or "system".

---

In your examples, I would call "software to extract structured data from web pages" a ***tool***, because the end-value is *the structured data* that some researcher will use for some purpose.  Your software is a *tool* for getting structured data from a wide range of web sites, and would suit a wide range of research purposes.

I would call your second example, "software for foreign language learning", a ***system*** if it includes all the functionality and usability features needed for an end user (however you define it) to use the software for some language learning purpose.  (I assume you mean "...to help people learn a foreign language" rather than "machine translation between natural languages".)  However, if your software is not a complete system from the viewpoint of some end user, and instead you want to focus on the *algorithms* that the software implements, then I'd call it an ***algorithm***.  There may be other possibilities, but I would need to know more specifics about the software and its use, and your purposes in publication.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer, my second software is focused on teaching "Spelling" and maybe "Listening" too. I can call it "a software tool for improving spelling and listening" or "A Spelling test and Tutoring System"?

Comment: @Ahmad - if the user of the software is seeking to be tutored, or is providing tutoring services, then "a tutoring system for foreign language spelling" is the best label I can think of.  "Tutoring" implies that the end-user has little expertise of their own in the subject and method and needs to be led through the process. I presume your software includes UI for end users, plus features such as saving previous scores/results, printing reports of results, etc.

Comment: Yes almost, maybe now it is in initial versions, but the ultimate goal of the software would be providing tests and reports of errors and adjusting the tests... then I go with "System"

Comment: _Following the practices of other people may lead you to follow their ambiguous or loose usage._ — As it should. The precise term doesn't matter to your audience, so it shouldn't matter to you, either.  For all practical purposes, the words are synonyms.  Your readers are going to pay far more attention what your software/system/application/tool/library/protocol/framework/implementation/widget/doohickey **does** than which specific word you use to describe it.

Answer (score 2):

Software, system, framework, application, and tool, along with several other words are often used to describe computer programs that accomplish a task. Application tends to be used when it is a standalone program that accomplishes the task, whereas library is more used when the code in question is intended to be used directly by other programs through an API of some sort. Frameworks often incorporate multiple libraries and/or applications to accomplish a broader set of goals. Tools tend to be smaller programs that are sharply focused on particular tasks, though through scope creep they often lose this focus over time. System frequently implies a much larger whole and is often used to speak of hardware/software systems (like a whole computer) as well as software alone.

These words have specific meaning in some contexts, but are often used somewhat interchangeably as well. It would be best to have a native English speaker in your field look over a few sentences that use your preferred words to make sure that they are consistent with your field's use of the terms. You may also compare to similar works, especially those you reference and those in journals or conferences where you'd like to publish, to get a feel for what the norms are.

Comment: Thank you, but I think many publication in various fields use the term *system* while it is not about hardware, in academia hardware is less discussed. For example a learning system, teaching system, ( I mean electronic not physical). I still didn't get the general meaning and proper use of *system* in publications.

Comment: By interchangeable you mean that in a single article I can use for example both "application" and "tool" or "software" and "system"?

Comment: @Ahmad, I think you can switch back and forth sometimes, but I would endeavor to be consistent. I wouldn't mix application and library, for example, but application and tool are probably OK to mix. Software and system may or may not be mixable depending on context, so I'd have to read some paragraphs to be sure.

Comment: _in academia hardware is less discussed_ — This is simply false.  Walk across the street to the EE building.

Comment: @Ahmad I must agree with JeffE. How do you have computer software without hardware?

Comment: @scaaahu maybe I can say in *computer science* (or in theoretical sciences) the software and algorithms are more focused.